# How to generate a specified number of Unique random numbers in R

Tags: r, random

I am trying to generate 25 random numbers with the range (1:10) by using `sample(rep(1:10), 25, replace = TRUE)`. The problem is out of the 25 generated numbers, sometimes there are only 7 or 8 unique numbers. I want to it have all the 10 numbers in the range 1-10.

Here is an example depicting the problem where the number 9 is missing:

```
> set.seed(7)
> unique(sample(rep(1:10), 25, replace = TRUE))
[1] 10  4  2  1  3  8  5  6  7
```

Comment: Why not just generate 15 random numbers and then add 1..10 to that?

Comment: @Dev: Can you please give an example using the seed?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know R, but if you really want all the numbers from 1 to 10 in there, they can't be random. Add them in yourself and then generate extra random numbers.

Comment: @Dev I agree, then the sequence isn't truly random.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Shuffling them afterwards can create random ordering, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
set.seed(7)
x <- c(sample(1:10, 10), sample(1:10, 15, replace = T))
length(unique(x))
x

[1] 10  4  1  8  2  9  6  3  7  5  2  3  8  1  5  1  6  1 10  4  7  3 10 10 10
```

Based on comments, this is pbb even shorter: `sample(c(1:10, sample(1:10, 15, replace = T)), 25)`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know R, so I wasn't able to turn my comment into code.

Comment: You could even add `sample(x, 25)` to have your sample in random order again.

Comment: Yes, because the first 10 numbers are always from 1 to 10. Good idea.